# Как с помощью команды sed удалить первые 10 строк из файла и сохранить изменения?

Tags: sed

```
sed -i `1,10d` file.txt
```

не работает

Comment: Ошибки может какие-то есть?

Comment: команда выполняется выводится корректно все, только вот сохранить не знаю как через > просто пустой файл оставляет

Comment: Если у вас GNU sed, `sed -i '1,10d' file`  работает на ура, откройте файл и увидите. В Mac OS надо добавить `sed -i '' '1,10d' file` или `sed -i'' '1,10d' file`

Comment: ну и так, к слову: кавычки должны быть либо одинарными (`'`), либо двойными (`"`), но уж никак не обратными (`\``)